# How can I add custom URL parameters to a MVC RedirectToAction

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I currently have a simple MVC RedirectToAction action:

```
return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Customers", new {Id = iNewId});
```

which redirects to `Cutomers/Edit/1`

However I'd like to append some custom values to the URL which will get used by javascript, returning URLs such as `Cutomers/Edit/1#Tab1`

What is the best method of doing this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
routes.MapRoute("WithTarget", "{controller}/{action}/{id}#{target}");
```

and

```
RedirectToAction("Edit", "Customers", new { id = iNewId, target = "Tab1" });
```

or

```
RedirectToRoute("WithTarget", new { controller = "Customers", action = "Edit", id = iNewId, target = "Tab1" });
```

But remember that the fragment is never sent from the client to the web server, so there's no way to read its value in a controller action.